# Use a higher number than the maximum float for the special function lambertw

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, scientific-computing

I am using the special function lambertw (`k=-1`) in Python 3 and I need to use it with numbers higher/lower than the maximum/minimum float number (`1.7976931348623157e+308`).

What can I do?

Also I tried with "decimal", but it did not work, i. e.,

```
from decimal import Decimal
from scipy.special import lambertw

lambertw(Decimal('3.1E+600'))
```

obtained this,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/share/apps/sistema/Python-3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/special/lambertw.py", line 107, in lambertw
return _lambertw(z, k, tol)
TypeError: ufunc '_lambertw' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Comment: The first thing you can do is post what you tried along with an explanation of why it did not work; telling people here that *"I tried with "decimal", but it did not work".* isn't helpful.

Comment: I would be surprised if `scipy.special.lambertw` works with `decimal.Decimal`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`mpmath`](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.6/modules/mpmath/index.html) library in [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) includes an implementation of [`lambertw`](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/mpmath/functions/powers.html#lambertw).  `mpmath` implements arbitrary precision floating point arithmetic.

Here's an example.  First, import `mpmath` from `sympy`, and set the digits of precision to 100 (chosen arbitrarily--change to fit your needs):

```
In [96]: from sympy import mpmath

In [97]: mpmath.mp.dps = 100
```

Verify that the `mpmath` function gives the same results as `scipy.special.lambertw`:

```
In [98]: from scipy.special import lambertw

In [99]: lambertw(123.45)
Out[99]: (3.5491328966138256+0j)

In [100]: mpmath.lambertw(123.45)
Out[100]: mpf('3.549132896613825444243187580460572741065183903716765715536934583554830913412258511917029758623080475405')
```

Compute `lambertw(3.1e600)`.   The argument is entered as a string, because we can't represent 3.1e600 as a regular floating point value.  `mpmath` will convert the string to a high-precision floating point value using the precision that we set earlier.

```
In [101]: mpmath.lambertw('3.1e600')
Out[101]: mpf('1375.455917376503282959382815269413629072666427317318260231463057587794635136887591876065911283365916388')
```

We can also create a variable `x` to hold the input value, and then call `mpmath.lambertw(x)`:

```
In [102]: x = mpmath.mpf('3.1e600')

In [103]: x
Out[103]: mpf('3.099999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999e+600')

In [104]: mpmath.lambertw(x)
Out[104]: mpf('1375.455917376503282959382815269413629072666427317318260231463057587794635136887591876065911283365916388')
```

The result can be represented as a regular floating point value, so we pass it to the builtin function `float()` to do the conversion:

```
In [105]: float(mpmath.lambertw(x))
Out[105]: 1375.455917376503
```

Answer (score 2):

The `decimal` module should be able to solve your problem. The issue you ran into may be that you did not set the precision higher than the default 28, [as mentioned in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html). To do that, just call `getcontext().prec = 100` or whatever degree of precision you need.

For instance, using your example number, I just ran this interactive session:

```
>>> decimal.getcontext().prec = 1000
>>> d = decimal.Decimal(1.7976931348623157e+308)
>>> d
Decimal('179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368')
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for your edit to the question, it was pretty vague at first. I did a bit of research and it looks like you just can't; scipy seems to only support native numeric types: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.types.html